# Dynamic Routing , Duplicate named routes definition

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am a Java programmer who has been studying dynamic route binding in Vue recently. Initially, I was able to navigate to different sub-routes without any issues and there were no error messages. However, when I refresh the page after navigating to a sub-route, an error occurs. Can someone help me identify the issue?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTTW2.png)

## router/index.js

```
import Vue, { computed } from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import store from '../store/index'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: () => import('../views/Home.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '/index',
        name: 'Index',
        component: () => import('../views/Index.vue')
      },
    ]
  },

  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: () => import('../views/Login.vue')
  },



]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let hasRouter = store.state.menus.hasRouter
  if (!hasRouter) {
    axios.get('/sys/menu/nav').then(
      res => {
        store.commit('setMenuList', res.data.data.menuList)
        store.commit('setPermList', res.data.data.permList)
        res.data.data.menuList.forEach(
          menu => {
            if (menu.children.length > 0) {
              menu.children.forEach(e => {
                // 转成路由                         
                let route = menuToRoute(e)
                if (route) {
                  router.addRoute('Home', route)
                }
              })
            }
          }
        )
        router.addRoute('Home', {
          path: '*',
          name: 'ERROR404',
          component: () => import('../views/error404.vue')
        })
        store.commit('sethasRouter', true)
      }
    )
  }
  next()

})

const menuToRoute = (menu) => {
  if (!menu.component) {
    return null;
  }
  let route = {
    name: menu.name,
    path: menu.path,
    meta: {
      title: menu.title,
      icon: menu.icon
    }
  }
  route.component = () => import(`@/views/${menu.component}`)
  return route
}

export default router
```

## mock data

```
 Mock.mock('/sys/menu/nav', 'get', () => {
  // 菜单json
  let menuList = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'SysManga',
      title: '系统管理',
      icon: 'el-icon-s-operation',
      path: '/SysManga',
      component: '',
      children: [
        {
          id :2,
          name: 'SysUser',
          title: '用户管理',
          icon: 'el-icon-s-custom',
          path: '/sys/users',
          component: 'sys/User',
          children: []
        },
        {
          id :3,
          name: 'SysRole',
          title: '角色管理',
          icon: 'el-icon-rank',
          path: '/sys/role',
          component: 'sys/Role',
          children: []
        },
        {
          id :4,
          name: 'SysMenu',
          title: '菜单管理',
          icon: 'el-icon-menu',
          path: '/sys/menu',
          component: 'sys/Menu',
          children: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id :5,
      name: 'SysTools',
      title: '系统工具',
      icon: 'el-icon-s-tools',
      path: '/SysTools',
      children: [
        {
          id :6,
          name: 'SysDict',
          title: '数字字典',
          icon: 'el-icon-s-order',
          path: '/sys/dicts',
          component: 'sys/Dicts',
          children: []
        },
      ]
    }]   
  // 权限数据
  let permList =['SysUser', "SysUser:save"]
  result.data = {
        menuList: [],
        permList: []
      }
  result.data.menuList = menuList
  result.data.permList = permList
 return result
    })
```

Comment: However, after a period of time when I raised the question, I found that the problem seemed to be solved, and the console no longer prompted duplicate routing warnings. I did almost nothing, confused.

Comment: If you already solved ur problem, I leave this here: Try importing `createWebHistory` from vue-router and use here: `const router = new VueRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(), routes
})`